# Angular controller function minification error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the Angular controller below. When it is run, I get the error "TypeError: t.getDealers is not a function". This is caused by the minification of the javascript. However, I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
myApp.controller('DLOController', ['$scope', 'DLOFactory',
    function ($scope, DLOFactory) {

        $scope.init = function () {
            $scope.searchType = [{ id: 1, name: "Search by Postcode" }, { id: 2, name: "Search by State" }, { id: 3, name: "Search by Dealer" }];
            $scope.selectedSearchType = 1;
            $scope.selectedState = -1;
            $scope.postcode = "";
            $scope.dealerName = "";
            $scope.states = [];
            $scope.dealers = [];

            getStates(2);
            getDealers(2);

        }

        function getStates(categoryType) {
            DLOFactory.getStates(categoryType)
                .success(function (val) {
                    $scope.states = val;
                })
            .error(function (error) {
                // REVISIT: LOG ERROR HERE.
            });
        }

        function getDealers(categoryType) {
            DLOFactory.getDealers(categoryType)
                .success(function (val) {
                    $scope.dealers = val;
                    console.log($scope.dealers);
                })
            .error(function (error) {
                // REVISIT: LOG ERROR HERE.
            });
        }

    }
]);
```

Here is my factory:

```
myApp.factory('DLOFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var stateList = [];
    var dealerList = [];

    return {
        getStates: function (categoryType) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Addresses/GetStateList',
                params: { categoryType: categoryType }
            })
            .success(function (responseData) {
                stateList.push(responseData);
            });
        },
        getStateList: function () {
            return stateList;
        },
        setStateList: function (sl) {
            stateList = sl;
        }
    }

    return {
        getDealers: function (categoryType) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Websites/GetDealers',
                params: { categoryType: categoryType }
            })
            .success(function (responseData) {
                dealerList.push(responseData);
            });
        },
        getDealerList: function () {
            return dealerList;
        },
        setDealerList: function (dl) {
            dealerList = dl;
        }

    }
}]);
```

The minified code looks like this:

```
myApp.controller("DLOController",["$scope","DLOFactory",function(n,t){function i(i){t.getStates(i).success(function(t){n.states=t}).error(function(){})}function r(i){t.getDealers(i).success(function(t){n.dealers=t;console.log(n.dealers)}).error(function(){})}n.init=function(){n.searchType=[{id:1,name:"Search by Postcode"},{id:2,name:"Search by State"},{id:3,name:"Search by Dealer"}];n.selectedSearchType=1;n.selectedState=-1;n.postcode="";n.dealerName="";n.states=[];n.dealers=[];i(2);r(2)}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two returns on the factory so second return won't execute. So merge both returns & try.

Comment: I tried that, but I get compilation errors. Can you please show me how to merge them both, as I'm new to this. thanks.